# Why has 64GB SD RPi Bullseye OS card "lost" half it's capacity after opening on PC

Tags: pi-3b+, sd-card, windows, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I attempted to set up a RP print server using Bullseye(32) on RP 3B+. There were issues that pointed to an i386 problem (...for another day..). I read Bookworm supported i368 so I decided to start over.

I tried to write Bookworm onto the SD using Raspberry Pi Imager on my Win11 PC by downloading Bookwork(64) file and using "custom" setting on RP Imager. The Imager gave "could not format disk" error. I tried to reformat SD using Windows's standard formater (right click in File Explorer), but got the same error. I tried Disk Management, but it showed only 26GB on my 64GB SD. That's it. **No unallocated space, unknown volumes, etc.** Half the capacity had disappeared!! The remaining 26GB (or lost space for that matter) seems *more* than would originally have been allocated to the win/pi shared partition & pi boot partition combined, and *less* than allocated for the pi's storage partition. It just seems to be "*half*".

Using admin privileges I used Diskpart to try to recover the space. I ran it both directly (win+R diskpart) and from 'cmd' run as administrator. I used the following commands:

1. DISKPART--> 
   diskpart > list disk > select disk 1 >  clean all  >
   create partition primary > format fs-ntfs > active 
   (inital attempts used "clean" instead of "clean all") 
   and then used
2. WINDOWS "right click" FORMAT to format to FAT32--> 
   I used "Restore Default setting (FAT32/16kb allocation units)
   and tried both quick and full format

I made several tries of the above. All formatted the SD fine, but failed to recover the lost data. I didn't notice this at first, but diskpart "size" shows only 26GB. And yes, it is a 64GB SD... I've used it before and "64GB" is even written right on it :)

Other info: (a) I use a direct contact SD card adapter with only copper between the SD and laptop USB contacts, no electronics (I've seen extenders or adapters can be an issue).  (b) The SD card is PNY brand 64GB micro SDXC. It is almost new. I used it as a Win sneaker-net for a few days before formatting it with Bullseye ~2 weeks ago.

I'm down a rabbit hole. Where did half my drive go and how/can I get it back? Is this a Pi, PC or formatting issue? My searches have turned up numerous "hidden" partition problems easily fixed by diskpart, but none speak to truly disappeared space. Replacement cost is not the issue, I'm just really really baffled... What happened?

I'd appreciate any insights.
[image: "Image of card with no data on it is as of this writing. I didn't take screenshots while troubleshooting. Sorry."]

Comment: `Is this a Pi, PC or formatting issue` or none of the above, could be a fault on the SD card itself

Comment: `I read Bookworm supported i368` - sure, Debian Bookworm runs on a lot of architectures, but a raspberry pi is not i386 - it's an ARM chip, nothing to do with intel/amd